# XamDataGrid column visibilty is not working using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, visibility, xamdatagrid

I'm trying to implement XamDataGrid column visibilty in a MVVM architecture and it does not seems to be working.

I'm doing the following:

Adding Visiblility property for an unbound field -

```
<igDP:UnboundField Name="gridCustomerId" 
                   Label="ID" 
                   Binding="{Binding customerid, 
                                     Mode=TwoWay, 
                                     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                   Visibility="{Binding ShowCustomerIDColumn, 
                                        Mode=TwoWay, 
                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

In my View Model, adding a proerty of Visibility type:

```
//ToShow CustomerID Column
private Visibility showCustomerIDColumn; 
public Visibility ShowCustomerIDColumn 
{
    get
    {
        return showCustomerIDColumn; 
    }

    set
    {
        showCustomerIDColumn=value; 
        InvokePropertyChanged("ShowCustomerIDColumn"); 
    }    
}
```

Then in the command handler using the following code:

```
if(ShowCustomerIDColumn == Visibility.Hidden) 
    ShowCustomerIDColumn = Visibility.Visible; 
else
    ShowCustomerIDColumn = Visibility.Hidden; 

InvokePropertyChanged("ShowCustomerIDColumn");
```

Anybody with a solution?

Cheers,
Anshuman

Answer (score 3):

The main reason why visibility is not working here cause **Visibility is not a dependency property in Fields Class(UnboundField class is derived from Field class)** unlike other properties.

**See visibility property**

[image: See visibility property]

**See Label/RowSpan Property that support binding**

[image: See Label Property that support binding]

**You need to set the visibility in c# code**(either in some behavior or code behind event):

```
fieldlayout.Fields[node.Name].Visibility = node.Visibility ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Comment: more precise code for access: `myXamDataGrid.FieldLayouts[0].Fields["myFieldName"].Visibility = myVisibility`
(note: sometimes the index can different than 0; note 2: you have define the `Name` property for the (Unound)Field)