# Binding DataGrid to Collection<List>

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid, infragistics

Can a `DataGrid` be bound to a `Collection<List>` type?

There are several questions on binding a `DataGrid` to a `Collection<Collection>` and it sort of worked for me too. But, I am looking specifically for `DataGrid` <-- Binding --> `Collection<List>`.

---

When I tried, the `List` is just getting displayed as an object on the `DataGrid` like:

> **Name** 
>   - System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Int32] 
>     **Value** 
>        Bob 
>         23 
>      43000 
>   + System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Int32]

### How is a `List` different from a `Collection` in this case?

A `List` doesn't have identifiers for entries and hence entries in a List cannot be automatically grouped into columns in a `DataGrid`.

#### Example:

In `Collection<List>`: 
entry1 contains the `List`: "Bob", 23, 43000 and 
entry2 contains the `List`: "Alice", 42, 71000.

Will I be able to use a `DataTemplate` for a `List` to get the following display? 
**Name   |  Age  |   Salary** 
  Bob    |    23 |     43000 
  Alice  |    42 |     71000

Notice that strings Name, Age and Salary aren't part of the `Lists`.

---

### My plan

1. Bind the **header** row to a `List<String>` to get the column names in the `DataGrid's` header.
2. Bind the **remaining** rows to `Collection<List>` to get the data populated in the `DataGrid`.

Specifially, I'm wondering if I can put these 3 strings (Name, Age, Salary) in a `List<String>` and bind only the header row to it. The remaining rows of the `DataGrid` can be bound to Collection.

**Is this even possible?**

---

Ideally, I would like to use *Infragistics'* `XamDataGrid`, but any solution to `DataGrid` will be a good starting point.

---

## EDIT

Why don't I use `Collection<Employee>`?
I would like to display only a **subset of columns** in the `DataGrid`.

I have about 5 screens which display columns from 2 types `Employee` and `EmployeeDetails`. Both these types have about 100 different properties each and I'm only interested in displaying about 20 properties as columns on each screen. Hence, I'm creating a `List` for each `Employee`/`EmployeeDetails` object that contains only these 20 properties.

The subset is defined at run-time by reading some config files. Hence, I can't statically define what I need to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use a binding converter to extract a member of your list:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value is List<string> && parameter is int)
    {
        return ((List<string>)value)[(int)parameter];
    }

    return null;
}
```

... but honestly I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Your list of strings represents the properties of an object, why don't just use a `Collection<Employee>` where `Employee` is

```
public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Bob
    {
        ...
    }

    public int Age
    {
        ...
    }

    public double Salary
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Strongly typed, much more readable, much more maintainable.

---

EDIT:

After reading your edit: definitely don't use a `List<string>`. Simply do not ask your XamDataGrid to automatically generate a column for each field. You've also [some examples](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/alex_fidanov/archive/2009/07/11/xamdatagrid-columnchooser-implementation.aspx) about how to hide columns.

---

EDIT:

It's **way much more MVVM friendly** to expose a `Collection<Employee>` property + write some code behind, than to expose `Collection<List<string>>`.

Remember the limitations of the XamDataGrid control are **purely** related to the view part of the MVVM pattern. **Don't change the ViewModel logic because of that**.

Also here's a related question that could help: [XamDataGrid column visibilty is not working using MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105461/xamdatagrid-column-visibilty-is-not-working-using-mvvm)

Comment: while I think about your answer, see the EDIT for why I'm not using `Collection<Employee>`.

Comment: also, the subset is defined at run-time by reading some config files. Hence, I can't statically define what I need to show.

Comment: @user640378 You can dynamically hide columns at runtime if you want (see example)

Comment: thanks for the updates. The issue with dynamically hiding columns is that I need to use `XamDataGrid`'s `FieldLayout`. That's going to require me to have code in the code-behind; I'm looking at _MVVM_-styled approaches.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound right.  The items that you show inside the Collection are just objects with properties.  Why not just have a collection of objects with those properties?

In order to iterate the second list, you would need another ItemsControl inside the bound row bound to that list as its data source.  Otherwise, you will always just receive the System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Int32]  binding value because that is the current level of what is being iterated.

If you wanted to keep it generic, you could even bind to a Collection, allowing the object to define its properties and in the Datagrid, only binding to the properties that it thinks should be visible (whether or not the object supports that).

Comment: Turn off auto generation of columns and you don't have to worry about 'creating a subset of columns'.  You just define what you want to show and that's what shows up.

Comment: well, the subset is defined at run-time by reading some config files. Hence, I can't statically define what I need to show.